# Select tabbed data in adb shell without using awk, as using awk gives `awk not found error`

Tags: android, shell, perl, awk, adb

I can get Receive and Transmit bytes for an android device as follows

```
130|sailfish:/ $ cat /proc/net/dev
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
rmnet_ipa0:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
r_rmnet_data7:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
r_rmnet_data4:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
rmnet_data1:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
rmnet_data3:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
 wlan0: 6720980481 66560024    0    0    0     0          0         0 355572166 1127583    0    2    0     0       0          0
rmnet_data5:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
r_rmnet_data1:       0       0    0    0    0     0          0         0        0       0    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Further, I am trying to filter the received and transmit bytes for an Android device using

`cat /proc/net/dev |grep wlan | awk {'print $1'}`

but I get the following error

```
/system/bin/sh: awk: not found
```

Any alternative way to select the appropriate columns?

---

I tried Perl as well as

```
cat /proc/net/dev | grep wlan   | perl -lane 'print $F[1]'
```

which gave

```
/system/bin/sh: perl: not found
```

---

using cut as

```
cat /proc/net/dev | grep wlan   | cut  -d' ' -f3
```

gives

```
6720980481
```

but the issues is that I want to cut the tab instead of space as I want to select other tabs as well

I tried

```
cat /proc/net/dev | grep wlan   | cut  -d'\t' -f3
```

and

```
cat /proc/net/dev | grep wlan   | cut  -d'    ' -f3
```

but it gives

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
```

Comment: the fact that some tool is not available to you is not the reason to put it in the title and list it as a tag.

Answer (score -1):

I guess one of the solutions would be to try and install awk and/or perl, but I guess that can't be done for some reason. Anyway, [tab is the default separator character in `cut`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucut.htm). So this should work

```
cat /proc/net/dev | grep wlan   | cut -f3
```

Comment: OP can not tell a part consecutive spaces from tabs. What he wanted was `grep wlan /proc/net/dev | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f3`.

Comment: @jjmerelo : the output of `cat /proc/net/dev | grep wlan   | cut -f3
` is same as that of `cat /proc/net/dev |grep wlan `

Comment: @AlexP. : you are right, your script worked, you can provide it as an answer.  Can you please tell me how can I select both `-f3` and `-f11`

Comment: @AlexP. The OP mentions '\t' in one of his/her examples, and talks about "cut the tab". Your code is OK as  long as it's only spaces and not tabs.

Comment: @AmarjitSingh That would happen if, as said above, it's spaces and not tabs. I just thought it was tabs as mentioned there.